# Convert a field in a Google Spreadsheet document from text to number using a formula ignoring text but keeping numbers

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google Spreadsheet document with a column which contains string data which includes both numbers and text. For example:

```
$39,90 + Tax
$69,90 + Tax
$20 / month
```

I want to sum all those values, but using SUM() doesn't work because of the text included in each field.
I've tried to create a new column and come up with a formula to convert those fields into:

```
39.90
69.90
20.00
```

But whatever I try, I always get `#VALUE!` or `#ERROR!`. So, how do I do this? (either directly sum all numbers contained in the original strings, or create a new column with only the numbers from the other column).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to SUM a row of numbers after extracting numbers with REGEX?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113306/how-to-sum-a-row-of-numbers-after-extracting-numbers-with-regex)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that doesn't work for me, because I don't have a fixed string to depend on, like the slashes in the question posted in that link (as you can see, I can have different strings after the numbers, like a plus sign, a slash or others...). Is there a regex to get a number with a . or a , in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
`=arrayformula(VALUE(substitute(regexextract(A1:A3,"[\d\,]+"),",",".")))`

This is essentially the answer offered by user135384 in [How to SUM a row of numbers after extracting numbers with REGEX?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/113307/196152). There are a few modifications:

- that topic was concerned with summing a range, so `sum()` was removed.
- the output is a string, so the opportunity is taken to `substitute` the "decimal comma" with a "decimal point".
- convert the string to a `value`.

---

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you!